# Existence of measurable maximum map.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $Y$ be metric compact, $X$ be a continuous image of complete separable metric space. Assume we have $f: Y \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ (s.a. $f$ is continuous w.r.t. the first argument and borel w.r.t. the second one). We want to prove that there is exist measurable $F : X \to Y$ s.a. $F(x)$ is maximum of $y \to f(y,x)$ for all $x$.

Intuitively we want to show that $\sup_y f(y, x)$ is measurable. But I don't know where should we use compactness of $Y$? Should it be covered with finite open sets, and then ...? Any hints.

UPD. as it was mentioned, we can consider the following task as measurability of $\pi_X(\{(x,y): f(y,x) > \epsilon\})$ for all $\epsilon$.

Comment: Have you tried to apply the definition of measurable? Or any other approach?

Comment: @supinf, the problem actually becomes easier if we consider the projection operator. So we want to show that: $\{x: F(x) > \epsilon\}$ is Borel-measurable for any $\epsilon$. Which forces us to consider $\pi_X(\{(y,x): f(y,x) > \epsilon\})$. But projection isn't always measurable, we can only say that this set is analytical.

Comment: @supinf hence we need to use somehow the compactness of $Y$ and the fact that $X$ is Suslin space, to obtain that measurability holds for projection map.

Comment: Maybe the exponential law (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exponential+law+for+spaces) is helpful here? (Idea: metric implies Hausdorffness, compact implies locally compact, therefore we have a one-to-one correspondence from $Hom(X \times Y, \mathbb{R}$ to $Hom(X, Hom(Y, \mathbb{R}))$

Comment: The result seems to be Theorem 8.2.11 in the monograph 'Set-valued analysis' by Aubin and Frankowska.